# QPlainTextEdit set font for only one line

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

Is that possible to display text with different fonts with `QPlainTextEdit`? 
i've tried this, but it seems that font changes for a moment for all widget and the returns to normal:

```
        QFont font;
        font.setBold(true);
        ui->plainTextEdit->setFont(font);
        ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText("Some text:\n");
        font.setBold(false);
        ui->plainTextEdit->setFont(font);
```

I've tried to change `QPlainTextEdit` to `QTextEdit` it didn't helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QPlainTextEdit` and `QTextEdit` both inherit `setFont` from `QWidget`, and a `QWidget` only has one font type at a time.

However, `QTextEdit` [exposes an interface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#public-slots) to set the font for different parts of the text via `QTextCharFormat`

In your case, the easiest way to fix this should be to use a `QTextEdit`, and the [`setCurrentFont`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setCurrentFont) method.

```
QFont font;
font.setBold(true);
ui->textEdit->setCurrentFont(font);
ui->textEdit->insertPlainText("Some text:\n");
font.setBold(false);
ui->textEdit->setCurrentFont(font);
```

(In this very specific case, you could also use `setFontWeight` to select bold/normal font, but for more general modifications `setCurrentFont` is more appropriate)